# The combination of cursor type and parallelism is not supported

Tags: cursor, cachedrowset

I'm use next code in method run of some thread:

```
RowSetFactory rowSetFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
@Cleanup CachedRowSet rowSet = rowSetFactory.createCachedRowSet();
...
...
...
rowSet.setCommand(execSql);
rowSet.setPageSize(100);
rowSet.execute(sourceConnection);
```

when i set page size into cachedRowSet i've got exception:

```
The combination of cursor type and parallelism is not supported.
```

if i use code without it, i have;nt exception.

in this case i make select from table with 20k rows it was take some time. I think if I'll use batch processing I reduce it.